# Stemming words in email addresses without putting them into arrays

Tags: python, classification, spam

I was trying to re-implement the spam classifier in the Stanford ML course by Andrew Ng and i used 'PorterStemmer()' but the emails after stemming is in a list form

```
ps = PorterStemmer()

for i in range(len(just_emails)):
    words = word_tokenize(just_emails[i])
    just_emails[i] = [ps.stem(w) for w in words]
print(just_emails.split()
```

but what i need to do is stem the words in the email and keep the emails in their original form

Actual Output: [go, until, jurong, point, crazi, avail, onli,...]

Desired Output : go until jurong point crazi avail onli

Comment: So what is the desired output if not a list? A string?

Comment: see one of the original Emails is like : 'go until  jurong point crazy  Available only in ...' what i want to do is keep it in the same form but have each and every word in it stemmed  , so it'd be like 'go until jurong point crazi avail onli ... '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression `just_emails.split()` produces a list, which is a Python data structure. If you `print` it, Python does a reasonable job of representing that data structure on your screen.

If you want it displayed in another form you have to say what form you expect. For example, if you want the words in the list strung together and separated by spaces, you actually have to say that. Like this:

```
print(' '.join(just_emails.split()))
```